# Unknown/unlabeled ports

Tags: laptop, ports, compaq-laptop

I have been looking into some of the Modular/Hardware Configurable/Customizable laptops, I own two Compaq Presario laptops, and although I can name Every port and slot on one of them, the other (an R3000/4000 with an AMD Athlon CPU), One of the ports, I can guess is an expansion port (for laptop docks, etc) The other, is unlabeled, and I have no idea what it is for, or what it does.

If someone could tell me what these two ports are, it would be nice.

I have three images that I gleaned from a google search, They are not mine, nor are they of the machine that I happen to own.
[Right IO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mkpy.png)
[The port in question for this image is the third from the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ33P.png)
[The port in question is the one on the far right, I know what the others are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33CzE.png)

Comment: Sorry, the post might have been hard  to read, so I'll sum it up here:
The first two images are of the port that I know what it is for, but I don't know what it is called. This port is the third from the right (in both images)

Comment: Quick edit: there is a third image, the port in the far right is the one that I both don't know what it is, nor do I know what it does, nor do I know what it is called.